# 'begin' has not been declared when used with a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iterator, stl-algorithm

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>

std::vector<std::string> vect;
std::vector<std::string> * vectP;

vect.push_back("ele0");
vect.push_back("ele1");

void func(){
    if(std::find(*vectP.begin(),*vecP.end(),"ele0")!=*vectP.end())
    //'begin' and 'end' have not been declared
}
```

Why are `begin` and `end` not declared when they're used with pointers? `*vectP` should be treated as if it's `vect` since it's dereferenced, or have I misunderstood something? How should I rectify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got your operator precedence wrong. `*vectP.begin()` means `*(vectP.begin())` (which doesn't work, of course), not `(*vectP).begin()`, which is what you mean. But you should probably spell that `vectP->begin()`.

Comment: Update: there has been memory leaks whenever `void func()` is called.

Comment: Update: memory leaks occur because of an unrelated issue. Will mark question as solved now. Thank you.